# Arrow functions as a block

Tags: syntax, lambda, expression, ecmascript-6, lexer

With es6 we could `(() => {})()`
Is there any way to write self-executing block in a way like we can do it in jsx? I mean, just `{ ["a"][0] }`, witch should return `"a"`.

What's I found so far http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=proposals:block_expressions&s=let

Comment: Well, for single expressions you can simply omit the block. For anything larger, the IIAF should be fine. Do you have a real-world problem that you could post as an example - maybe theres a better solution?

Comment: yes, you definitely right. I don't think that such thing have any significant practical application ). I understood now why Arrow-functions called so ). Thank you for your explanation! )

Answer (score 0):

Now I realized that such syntax actually have no significant practical application.

Thank @Bergi for the comment!

> Well, for single expressions you can simply omit the block. For
>   anything larger, the IIAF should be fine. Do you have a real-world
>   problem that you could post as an example - maybe theres a better
>   solution? –